# How do I condition a really noisy pulse for a 3.3V microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, signal

I'm reading the pulse from my spark pulse on an old motorcycle and finally got a decent pulse, but it's too high for mere microcontrollers to use (~10V ±6V). I've attached a picture below, but disregard the voltage level and AC. After some adjustments the voltage is about 10 and in DC.

My goal is to get the signal to just clamp at 3.1V or so and hold till it drops out cleanly (no hiccups to trigger again).

[image: Spark Pulse Signal]

Do you guys think the circuit below will be what I need?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbkwFD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Capacitor DIScharge path is very slow due to 50k. You have about 5 second time constant. Charge is also too slow. RC product must be usefully less than interspark rate. If you MUST have no hassles with bounce then using a Schmitt trigger will help heaps (hardware or software).

Comment: How about using the opto-coupler.

Comment: I was told those were too slow... is that a misnomer?

Comment: There are high speed optocouplers which can pass a 1 MHz digital signal ([example](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-3712EN), the link goes to a PDF datasheet).  They usually have a push-pull output, as opposed to open-collector or open-drain.  +1 to Anand, by the way.

Comment: a two stroke running at 5k rpm will still only be 60hz, fast enough for an opto

Comment: Change 6.7 kOhm to 330 Ohm. Change 100 uF to 10 nF. Change 50 kOhm to 50 Ohm. Add a 220 Ohm resistor between 3.3V digital in and ground, which will double as discharge resistor for the smoothing cap. Note that Zeners will not build up their full voltage until they get a fair bit of current -- about 5 mA -- through them. At the same time, they are not instantly fast, so there may be overshoot, too. The resistor divider made by the values will at most generate 3.6V if the Zener is too slow, yet will hopefully have enough current to keep the Zener up at 3.3V.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Zener clamp will probably work as you expect.  
   (Another way of achieving a similar result is to clamp with a Schottky diode between signal and +3.3V supply rail.)
2. 100μF seems too large for a smoothing capacitor.  Together with 6.7k, the 100μF will give you an RC time constant of 2.1sec.  That's too slow for a fast pulse, which lasts less than 1ms.  Somewhere between 0.01μF and 0.1μF might work better.
3. Do you have a bleed resistor in parallel with the smoothing cap?  Otherwise, it will not discharge between the pulses, and output will remain high all the time.

**P.S.**  It's nice that you've labeled the purposes of your components.   But designate the components in the schematic too:  R1, D1, D2, C1.  In the comments, it's easier to say "D1" and C1 than "direction diode" and "smoothing capacitor".

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use an opamp here. Or a comparator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnlguY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With the given values, an input voltage of 20V will generate (20-12)/22 Amps of current, so the Zener doesn't see over-current. (Which will kill it and make it ground out.) Meanwhile, an input of 10V will generate a (10*1/(5+1)) == 1.7 V potential at the "+" line on the opamp. Meanwhile, the "-" reference line will have a steady (3.3*2/(10+2)) == 0.5V, so you start getting a pulse at way below 10V. If you want to smooth it, a 1 - 10 nF capacitor between the opamp + terminal and ground would accomplish that.

I think using a higher voltage Zener diode is better than the 3.3V proposed in the other circuit. Higher voltage Zeners are generally more well behaved -- close to 3.3V, I have experienced that they get finicky, with capacitances going up and leakage/stand-off/response curve being mushier.